# Numpy array multiple condition boolean

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean

I want my array to pass two conditions. If I try to do this with just one I don't have any problems but if I'll give code two conditions python crashes. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

queue = deque([], maxlen=10)

queue.appendleft(31)
queue.appendleft(32)
queue.appendleft(33)

cond1 = 35
cond2 = 30

A_1 = np.array(queue)

print(cond2 > A_1 < cond1)
# print(A_1 > 30)  # works
# array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

print(((cond2 > A_1 < cond1).sum() == A_1.size).astype(np.int))
# print(((A_1 > 30).sum() == A_1.size).astype(np.int))  # works
# 1
```

Comment: Numpy does not support shorthand operators. Please explicitly state them like this: `(cond2 > A_1) & (A_1 < cond1)`

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the second condition is doing, but it doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for answer. I want my array to be in certain range to be accepted. I don't want it to be bigger than specific value and I don't want it to be lower than certain value. Also with & now all values are false and they shouldn't be.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand what  `((cond2 > A_1 < cond1).sum() == A_1.size).astype(np.int)` is trying to do.

Comment: @coldspeed If everything is True then return 1 if one value doesn't match my condition then return 0 (False)

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense. Anyway, the solution in my first comment should work, in case you didn't see it yet.

Comment: @coldspeed I used it and it returns False, False, False while it should be True, True, True. unless I'm total dumbass and I've done something wrong

Comment: Well, yea, you switched it up: `(cond1 > A_1) & (A_1 < cond2)`... does that make more sense now?

Comment: @coldspeed It still returns False for everything. Check it out yourself.

Comment: `(A_1 > 30) & (A_1 < 35)` why should this not work? Now just let `cond1 = 30; cond2 = 35` for the sake of everyone's sanity here.

Comment: I understand and I know it should but I'm telling you it doesn't work. Copy code and try to do this yourself.

Comment: https://ideone.com/CFEtD3

Comment: Yeah if I'll copy it from link it works. I don't know what is wrong with my code I must be blind or something. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a random example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123456)

array = np.array(np.random.randn(12))

print((array < 1) & (array > 0))
```

And numpy you have to put the conditions in parenthesis, and then use the & operator for an and condition. For an or condition you use the | operator and then follow the same format. This will get you an array of Boolean values.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It doesn't work with my example. Everything returns False.

Comment: @Hsin This is just pseudo code. You may have zero examples in your code that return if you set the condition to the specific ones that I specified. If you set the conditions to the ones that YOU want, what does your code return?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like `np.logical_and(A_1 < cond1, A_1 > cond2)`

If you want to check if all the elements satisfy, just `np.all(np.logical_and(A_1 < cond1, A_1 > cond2))`

`cond2 > A_1 < cond1` won't work as desired because `cond2 > A_1` returns a bool array. Compare boolean values with `cond1` is not wanted according to your description. To be explicit, one can use `np.logical_and`.